# Wordnet for other languages

Tags: data-request, dictionary, wordnet

I'm looking for downloadable [wordnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet) for other languages. Preferably connected to the [Princeton WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/). Is there any?

Answer (score 2):

You can get Wordnet for many languages at 
[GlobalWordnet](http://globalwordnet.org/wordnets-in-the-world/)

Answer (score 2):

There is also [BabelNet](http://babelnet.org/about).

> BabelNet is both a multilingual encyclopedic dictionary, with
>   lexicographic and encyclopedic coverage of terms, and a semantic
>   network which connects concepts and named entities in a very large
>   network of semantic relations, made up of about 16 million entries,
>   called Babel synsets.
>
> BabelNet 4.0 covers 284 languages and is obtained from the automatic integration of:
>
> - [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), a popular computational lexicon of English (version 3.0)
> - [Open Multilingual WordNet](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/), a collection of wordnets available in different languages
> - ...

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724795/translate-nouns-using-sparql-with-babelnet) is an example of how to translate words with BabelNet in SPARQL.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Open Multilingual Wordnet](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/) project by Francis Bond at Nanyang Technological University, Singapore. They have wordnets built from wiktionary and other resources for many languages under an open licence.